# npm ELIFECYCLE error with npm run start-server

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` when I try to run my server command

**What I'm trying to do is**
[TensorFlow.js Training in Node.js](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-nodejs-codelab/?hl=pt_br#0)
It's for college, step 3 says to try out the server I get this

**package.json snip**

```
"scripts": {
    "start-client": "webpack && webpack-dev-server",
    "start-server": "node server.js"
  },
```

**error message**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\leo\baseball>npm run start-server

> tfjs-examples-baseball-node@0.2.0 start-server C:\xampp\htdocs\leo\baseball
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
\\?\C:\xampp\htdocs\leo\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v5\tfjs_binding.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\leo\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:58:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tfjs-examples-baseball-node@0.2.0 start-server: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tfjs-examples-baseball-node@0.2.0 start-server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-11T07_01_54_120Z-debug.log
```

**server.js**

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const pitch_type = require('./pitch_type');

const TIMEOUT_BETWEEN_EPOCHS_MS = 500;
const PORT = 8001;

// util function to sleep for a given ms
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Main function to start server, perform model training, and emit stats via the socket connection
async function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || PORT;
  const server = http.createServer();
  const io = socketio(server);

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`  > Running socket on port: ${port}`);
  });

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('predictSample', async (sample) => {
      io.emit('predictResult', await pitch_type.predictSample(sample));
    });
  });

  let numTrainingIterations = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < numTrainingIterations; i++) {
    console.log(`Training iteration : ${i+1} / ${numTrainingIterations}`);
    await pitch_type.model.fitDataset(pitch_type.trainingData, {epochs: 1});
    console.log('accuracyPerClass', await pitch_type.evaluate(true));
    await sleep(TIMEOUT_BETWEEN_EPOCHS_MS);
  }

  io.emit('trainingComplete', true);
}

run();
```

I already tried:

- `cache clean --force/-f`, delete node_modules package-lock.json run npm install
- removing package-lock.json and running the server
- `npm install -g node-pre-gyp`
- `npm install --unsafe-perm`
- Changing the port from 8001 to 10000 3000 80
- running it with every single thing else on my computer closed (this includes my xampp on the bg)

some info

- node -v 14.15.1
- npm -v 6.14.8
- windows 10 x64

My grade needs me to overcome this and finish the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

line 13 of my error accused something wrong at line 58 at this file

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\leo\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:58:16)
```

opened the file and commented the line, code ran without problems